# How do I handle forms in Site.Master?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

I have a partial view thats being rendered in my Site.Master file (footer), and it contains a form - im able to submit values and itll throw it to the controller just fine..the problem is when validation fails and i need to go back to the form to display errors

How can i have a form that uses a viewmodel inside Site.Master and still be able to throw it back and post validation errors?

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewMasterPage" %>
```

I wont be able to inherit using  here...i dont think

Thanks

Comment: You could use a strongly typed partial with a form inside.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a strongly typed partial with a form inside then pass the ModelState in TempData and add the errors back into ModelState in the partialview. I would definitely performed client side validation as well.

Another option is to submit the form via Ajax. It is very simple to do with Jquery.Forms.js

http://malsup.com/jquery/form/

Comment: Ya i think ill go the ajax route - seems like ajax/jquery is always the answer lol

Comment: I hear you on that one, and it is so easy with MVC! Best of luck on your project!